# Google Cloud API execution from Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have been struggling to make google sdk work from AWS lambda function but the entire Google documentation and API executions seem very confusing.

I have lambda function and added Google-Resource-manager and Google-cloud packages as layers. As per [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-resource-manager/samples/generated_samples/cloudresourcemanager_v3_generated_tag_values_update_tag_value_async.py), I am trying to get list of existing projects from the parent folder

1. Generating tokens from Service Account (I have Service account json stored in secret manager)
2. Then list the projects

Here my lambda function code

```html
import json,os
from datetime import date
import boto3, requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
#from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    credentails = get_secret("mysecret")
    print(credentails)
    print(credentails['type'])
    json_acct_info = {
        "type":credentails["type"],
        "project_id":credentails["project_id"],
        "private_key_id":credentails["private_key_id"],
        "private_key":credentails["private_key"],
        "client_email":credentails["client_email"],
        "client_id":credentails["client_id"],
        "auth_uri":credentails["auth_uri"],
        "token_uri":credentails["token_uri"],
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":credentails["auth_provider_x509_cert_url"],
        "client_x509_cert_url":credentails["client_x509_cert_url"],
        "universe_domain":credentails["universe_domain"],
        "type":credentails["type"],
    }
    
    json_acct_info = json.dumps(json_acct_info)
    
    print(json_acct_info)
    try:
        
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
        gcredentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json_acct_info,scopes=SCOPES)
        print(gcredentials)
        return {"responseCode":200,"message":gcredentials}
    except Exception as err:
        raise err




def get_secret(secret_name):
    print("inside get_secret",secret_name)
    region_name = "us-west-2"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except Exception as err:
        raise err
    else:
        return json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
```

When executing lambda, I am getting the below error, I not sure if I am missing something in code or the packages attached layer.

```html
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'gcp_get_assignment_role_data': cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/opt/python/grpc/_cython/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "8fc3cabe-9aa2-442d-aaaf-3c9c7222577e",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: This seem like a wrong version of the library: `cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'`. Check: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1540

Comment: Check if the all the grpcio and grpcio-tools packages compatible with the Lambda python version of yours